# Gomobile library uses hidden API method

Tags: android, go, android-ndk, aar, gomobile

I have an **Android** application which uses a **Golang** library (**.aar**) created with **Gomobile**. Anytime the application tries to create an instance of a class from the library or calls a library method it crashes with the next log message:

```
W/om.example.cal: Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/AppGlobals;->getInitialApplication()Landroid/app/Application; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 11110 (om.example.calc), pid 11075 (om.example.calc)
Application terminated.
```

`getInitialApplication` method is located in [Google's light greylist (line 349)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/85c81cb24c5d71fc79dea3ba498d1a509895bb01/config/hiddenapi-p-light-greylist.txt). 
I know it's impossible to access any hidden method on SDK version 28 and higher, that's why I wrote the next in `build.gradle` (26 is the least version for **Play Market**):

```
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 26
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

But it didn't help. How to make it work?
Remarks: test device is **Nexus S** emulated on **Ubuntu 18.04**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I debugged my application on the emulator. Apparently, it's incompatible with native libraries. Debugging on a phone is alright.